# GoogleMapでinfowindowを編集したい

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Android開発初心者です。
AndroidStudioを使用しています。
GoogleMap上のマーカーをタップした時、マーカー位置の情報をinfowindowで表示させることはできたのですが、このinfowindowをユーザー側で編集できるようにしたい。
調べているのですが、php記述ばかりでjavaだとどのように書けばいいのかわからない状態です。。。

Comment: 具体的に誰がどうやって、どのように編集したいのですか

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps Android APIでinfoWindowをカスタマイズしたい場合はInfoWindowAdapterを利用します。

下記、サイトを参考にしてみてください。
[インフォウィンドウをカスタマイズする](http://seesaawiki.jp/w/moonlight_aska/lite/d/%A5%A4%A5%F3%A5%D5%A5%A9%A5%A6%A5%A3%A5%F3%A5%C9%A5%A6%A4%F2%A5%AB%A5%B9%A5%BF%A5%DE%A5%A4%A5%BA%A4%B9%A4%EB)
[Google Maps Android API公式ガイド](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows#custom_info_windows)